# find all combinations of 3 Keys in Object

Tags: javascript, math

Given an object with **n** keys, need to find all combinations of every 3 keys (**nC3** in math)

is this the most efficient way?

```
var x = {};  // object

x['00'] = [1, 7, 9];
x['01'] = [1, 9];
x['02'] = [6, 8];
x['03'] = [1, 7];
x['04'] = [1, 5, 8];
x['05'] = [4, 6, 8, 9];

var triples = [],
    c = [0,0,0]; // counter. keep track of the indexes when looping over objects

for(var i in x){
    c[0]++;
    c[1] = 0;

    for(var j in x){ // loop to compare this x[i] array to all other arrays
        c[1]++;
        if( c[1] < c[0]+1 ) continue;
        c[2] = 0;

        for(var k in x){
            c[2]++;
            if( c[2] < c[1]+1 ) continue;

            triples.push( [i,j,k] );
        }
    }
}

console.dir(triples);
```

Comment: Could you show your desired output?

Comment: what I've posted is already the desired output...I just want to know if there's a better way

Comment: no you haven't posted your desired output. you've posted a program, which we have to go run if we want to see what it outputs, and we have to assume its output does what you want it to do. Consider saving us the trouble and posting desired output directly.

Comment: the output is too long to post, therefor I haven't done so, in consideration for proper readability. also note that this question is very clear of type (find nCr in set of arrays). if one doesn't understand that...he's probably not the man for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet, by my guess, is to iterate through the keys and then push based on that. This way you avoid what basically amounts to a long series of String lookups -- something that JS is generally good at, but not nearly as fast as simple numeric iteration.

It would be something like this:

```
var keys = []
for( var it in x ) keys.push(it);

var triples = []
var len = keys.length; //cache the value.
for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ )
   for( var j = i + 1; j < len; j++ )
      for( var k = j + 1; k < len; k++ )
         triples.push( [ keys[ i ], keys[ j ], keys[ k ] ] );
```

Comment: very clever indeed :) you transformed the Object into a dictionary Array thus it's possible to use normal `for` loops and skip items

Comment: will you be king enough to show an example using a recursive method?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `for .. in ..`, it's slow and can give problems. Just use a `for` loop.

Why do you only go 3 deep? In your example you have a set with 4. I would expect some recursive solution.

As for your question: *is this the most efficient way?*

If you are truly looking for the most efficient way you'll probably end up with a different script for each browser (or JavaScript engine to be precise).

I'd focus on a working implementation because I don't think it's doing even that right now.

Comment: but it's working perfectly. how can you use anything BUT a `for...in` loop on an object? not making sense.. I need it to be fast because this is a part of something big, that will run many times over

Comment: Then I don't understand your algorithm.

Comment: how can you not understand ~10 lines of simple loops that works well..?